# fetch value from array within array within array

Tags: php, arrays

I have trouble understanding arrays. For example, I got the following data.

```
array(
  label=> person1
  start=> 2014-10-10
  end=> 2014-10-11
  class=> annual
)
array(
  label=> person2
  start=> 2014-10-08
  end=> 2014-10-08
  class=> sick
)
array(
  label=> person1
  start=> 2014-10-01
  end=> 2014-10-03
  class=> sick
)
array(
  label=> person3
  start=> 2014-10-20
  end=> 2014-10-20
  class=> annual
)
array(
  label=> person1
  start=> 2014-10-29
  end=> 2014-10-29
  class=> compassionate
)
```

And I want to arrange it this way

```
array(
     [person1]=>array(
            array(
                start=> 2014-10-10
                end=> 2014-10-11
                class=> annual),
            array(
                start=> 2014-10-01
                end=> 2014-10-03
                class=> sick),
            array(
                 start=> 2014-10-29
                 end=> 2014-10-29
                 class=> compassionate), 
            ),
      [person2]=>array(
                 start=> 2014-10-08
                 end=> 2014-10-08
                 class=> sick),
      [person3]=>array(
                 start=> 2014-10-20
                 end=> 2014-10-20
                 class=> annual)
)
```

My requirement is to display the data with same label in the same row.
This is the code I used but it does not works at all.

```
var $blocks = array();
var $data = array();
var $blocksByLabel = array();

global $blocksByLabel;
global $blocks;

foreach($this->data as $d) {
     foreach ($this->blocks as $block) {
         $label = $block->$d['label'];
              if (!array_key_exists($d['label'], $blocksByLabel)){
                    $blocksByLabel[$block->label] = array();
               }
array_push($blocksByLabel[$block->label], $blocks);
         }


  $this->blocks[] = array(
    'label' => $d['label'],
    'start' => $start = strtotime($d['start']),
    'end'   => $end   = strtotime($d['end']),
    'class' => @$d['class']
  );
```

Comment: If this is PHP, there is a basic misunderstanding about strings and constants. You have to put all the keys and values in quotes. As you write it, they are undefined constants. Undefined constants raise warnings and not errors and are assumed to represent themselves. You should never use undefined constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

`$old_array` is the source array and `$new_array` is the rearanged array

```
foreach($old_array as $r) {
  $new_array[$r['label']][] = array("start" => $r['start'],
                                    "end"   => $r['end'],
                                    "class" => $r['class']);
}
```

this should arrange your array the way you want.. and you should rename the old_array and new_array based on your variable names..

***ADDED RUNNING PROGRAM for further clarification***

here is my running code:

```
<?php
  $old_array[] = array("label" => "person1", "start" => "2014-10-10", "end" => "2014-10-11", "class" => "anual");
  $old_array[] = array("label" => "person2", "start" => "2014-10-08", "end" => "2014-10-08", "class" => "sick");
  $old_array[] = array("label" => "person1", "start" => "2014-10-01", "end" => "2014-10-03", "class" => "sick");
  $old_array[] = array("label" => "person3", "start" => "2014-10-20", "end" => "2014-10-20", "class" => "anual");
  $old_array[] = array("label" => "person1", "start" => "2014-10-29", "end" => "2014-10-29", "class" => "compassionate");

  foreach($old_array as $r) {
    $new_array[$r['label']][] = array("start" => $r['start'],
                                "end" => $r['end'],
                                "class" => $r['class']);
  }

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($new_array);
  echo "</pre>";
?>
```

after execution, the output should be:

```
Array
(
    [person1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [start] => 2014-10-10
                    [end] => 2014-10-11
                    [class] => anual
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [start] => 2014-10-01
                    [end] => 2014-10-03
                    [class] => sick
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [start] => 2014-10-29
                    [end] => 2014-10-29
                    [class] => compassionate
                )

        )

    [person2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [start] => 2014-10-08
                    [end] => 2014-10-08
                    [class] => sick
                )

        )

    [person3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [start] => 2014-10-20
                    [end] => 2014-10-20
                    [class] => anual
                )

        )

)
```

the code for rearranging the array is working fine.. please check your `$this->data` variable through `var_dump($this->data)` to check the variable's content.. (if the source array doesn't have value, of course the result would have no value either)..

hope this helps..

Comment: thanks a lot for the help..but the code didn't display the result.. my table is blank but it didn't have any warning message either...

Comment: `foreach($this->data as $d){
  $this->blocks[$d['label']][]=array(
   "start"=>$start = strtotime($d['start']),
   "end"=>$end = strtotime($d['end']),
   "class"=>$d['class']);
  
      if(!$this->first || $this->first > $start) $this->first = $start;
      if(!$this->last || $this->last < $end)   $this->last  = $end;
          
    }`

Comment: maybe you have problem getting the data in `$this->data` try to use `var_dump($this->data)` so you'll see the content of the variable, I'll provide you a running sample of my code so that you can see that its working fine and so that you can have confidence in testing your code in it...

Comment: then what is the array structure inside `$this->data`.. it should work if its the same as your question above..